# offset problems in jquery, works on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, contentoffset

I'm using an anchor navigation on my website & a fixed header.
by clicking on a link of my menu, the page scrolls to the linked #.
I've added a JS code to calculate the height of my header and to add the height to my # link so it the section is not displayed under my fixed header.
it works fine on chrome, but not on firefox, I don't understand what I am doing wrong, can anybody help me with this ?
here is the js code :

```
function scrolling(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        var offset  = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
        //alert(offset);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-offset
            //--OFFSET--//
        }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
}
```

and css :

```
#header{position: fixed;z-index: 1000;top: 0;padding-left:25px;padding-top: 20px;height: 75px;width:100%;min-width:590px}
```

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This question could do with a JSFiddle, with HTML to put the code in context.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, here is a jsfiddle, thanks for your help http://jsfiddle.net/rHmAA/3/

Comment: It is something to do with the dual scrolling of `html` and `body` together with your header styling. A simple `window.scrollTo` instead does go to the correct offset in FireFox too. I see other SO questions that mention `$('html, body').animate('scrollTop',...)` does not work in all cases. This looks like one of those cases. As an alternative I tried making `#wrapper` the scrolling area, but introduced new position bugs: http://jsfiddle.net/rHmAA/7/ Perhaps this will provide a better starting point to avoid the cross browser issues?